# Sitemap.php->generateXml() is not used

Tags: sitemaps

It almost seems like Magento is taking the `sitemap.xml` from cache even though I'm regenerating it.

In the sitemap admin page, I'm pressing `generate`. But the function `generateXml()` in `app/code/core/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php` is never called.

Curiously, if I remove sitemap.xml, it will reappear with the old content, `generateXml()` still not being called.

Is there a caching system which could be responsible for this? Am I using the wrong file or am I assuming the function should be called even though it shouldn't? Any other reasons?

Comment: Which Sitemap.php are you referring to? there are 7.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean the Model: app/code/core/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I feel dumbstruck now.

There was a module which was overriding the Sitemap.php AGAIN. So obviously, the code in there was being used.

Anyways, thanks for the help, maybe this will help another poor developer one day.